# How to create and use byte array with javax.script

Tags: java, javax.script

Can we create primitive arrays like byte array or int array using javax.script?

Comment: You either create the array in Java the normal way or you create it in the scripting language.  How you do that depends on the language scripted.

Answer (score 7):

To create a Java Array of 10 bytes in Mozilla's Rhino:

```
var buff = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.Byte.TYPE, 10)
```

Notice that java array is different type than native JavScript array - they both can be used in Rhino JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `JavaScript` engine of the package, use

```
var array = new Array();
array[0] = 1;
```

I'd recommend a reading through

[`Java Docs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html)  [`Java6Master`](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aQz6rmi2HM04J%3abooks.brainysoftware.com/java6_sample/chapter3.pdf%20javax.script%20package&hl=en&gl=in&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESh0Mk7iv9TITh3u3BTEfFLZrjC25CSJkZysit_juU_2eevLbEWpOfLiqZ1l9TucKAKV-n9pmRpp4npqYMT71dNi6nlIFG5JLQweXJbfjyG9xy95lllh8kBSbQwomE_PU5IFo98I&sig=AHIEtbSGeOyqkejp1OzMK5sD4jzMGFyAYQ)  [`Java Scripting Programmer's Guide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)

Comment: Basically, it needs to be an array of 1024 bytes size. 
In Java, it used to be byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
But in javax.script with javascript, I can not find a way to do this.